# Couldn't start nginx-proxy docker image with error "Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change"

Tags: docker, nginx

I am playing with "nginx-proxy", pulled the image "jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest" to my local host, tried to start it but got this error "*Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'*", and when I tried to go to the server at port 80: it returned 503 Bad Gateway:

Here is my docker-compose file:

`version: '3.0'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /docker/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    network_mode: "bridge"`

and the error I've got

`WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one is being generated in the background.Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2018/07/18 04:14:14 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 1 containers
dockergen.1 | 2018/07/18 04:14:14 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2018/07/18 04:14:14 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2018/07/18 04:14:14 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'`

Any idea is much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: 503 or 502 bad gateway?

Answer (score 3):

It's default behavior for this image, you can see `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 503;
}
```

So when your visit, it will give `503` error.

This is a service discovery service, so you need to use it.

See the official example:

*docker-compose.yaml*

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local
```

If you use `docker-compose up` to start it, then have a look at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` again, you will see:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 503;
}
# whoami.local
upstream whoami.local {
    ## Can be connected with "a_default" network
    # a_whoami_1
    server 172.20.0.2:8000;
}
server {
    server_name whoami.local;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://whoami.local;
    }
}
```

Here, `jwilder/nginx-proxy` watch the events of docker, and add a proxy to nginx reverse settings.

So if execute `curl -H "Host: whoami.local" localhost` on your host machine, it will print `I'm 5b129ab83266`.

`server 172.20.0.2` in nginx settings is your application container's ip, it will changes everytime you start a new container, so with this method, you can free to know the ip of your application container, just use `inverse proxy from nginx`.

Many service such as `marathon-lb` which is a component of `marathon` who known as a mesos framework also could afford such function, maybe `k8s` also? Anyway, you need to know principle of this image, a useful doc for your reference: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Hung Vu, was that the entirety of your docker-compose file, or just the section for jwilder/nginx-proxy? I ask because **I experienced this error when I had simply forgotten to add the "virtual_host" environment variable for my other services**, after dropping in that service definition for the nginx-proxy. Doh! :-) See its docs, or atline's example here.

Answer (score 0):

*I ran into this issue in 2021, but I was able to resolve it. Documenting as this thread is at the top of Google searches.*

**tl;dr: Run the containers without a custom NGINX config at least once**

This happened to me as I was migrating from one host to another. I migrated all of my files over and then started running my containers one by one.

For me, I had a custom NGINX config file that proxied a path to a separate docker container that was not created yet.

```
  - "~/gotti/volumes/nginx-configs:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
```

in this mount, I had a mydomain.conm config file with the following contents

```
# reverse proxy
location /help {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://ghost:2368; <----- Problem: This container didn't exist yet.
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

This invalid reference prevented NGINX from proxying my app and thus prevented a SSL cert from being issued.